# grunt-watch infinite loop

Tags: sass, gruntjs, infinite-loop

I've set up a project with grunt watch (for coffee and scss files essentially). I've got a infinite loop issue.

here is my Gruntfile.js file:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.initConfig({

        coffeelint: {
            dist: ['coffee/*.coffee'],
            server: ['coffee/*.coffee']
        },

        coffee: {
            dist: {
                compile: {
                    files: {
                        'js/hscroll.js': 'coffee/*.coffee'
                    }
                }
            },
            server: {
                compileWithMaps: {
                    options: {
                        bare: true,
                        sourceMap: true
                    },
                    files: {
                        'js/hscroll.js': 'coffee/*.coffee',
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        uglify: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'js/hscroll.min.js': ['js/hscroll.js']
                }
            }
        },

        watch: {
            coffee: {
                files: ['coffee/*.coffee'],
                tasks: ['coffeelint:server', 'coffee:server']
            },
            compass: {
                files: ['sass/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['compass:server']
            }
        },

        compass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    sassDir: 'sass',
                    cssDir: 'stylesheets',
                }
            },
            server: {
                options: {
                    debugInfo: true,
                    sassDir: '/sass',
                    cssDir: '.tmp',
                    relativeAssets: false,
                    assetCacheBuster: false
                }
            }
        },

        clean: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    dot: true,
                    src: '.tmp'
                }]
            },
            server: '.tmp'
        },
    });

    grunt.registerTask('dist', ['clean:dist', 'coffeelint:dist', 'coffee:dist', 'compass:dist', 'uglify:dist']);

    grunt.registerTask('watch', [
        'clean:server',
        'coffeelint:server',
        'coffee:server',
        'compass:server',
        'watch'
    ]);
};
```

It loops when I launch 'grunt watch', I don't unserstand why?

Perhaps a newbie questions, but any help will be welcome....

Thanks.

My folder structure is: 
hscroll>
  css
  .sass.cache (I used compass)
  coffee
  css
  sass
  stylesheets

grunt dist works perfectly.

Thanks.

Comment: What does the output look like? Always include output, since many times the assumptions regarding what the output means are wrong.

Comment: Not saying that _is_ the case here, just that it might be.

Answer (score 4):

I think I've found the issue. By registering a task called `watch` which itself call the watch task. I've created the loop. I just deleted

```
grunt.registerTask('watch', [
        'clean:server',
        'coffeelint:server',
        'coffee:server',
        'compass:server',
        'watch'
]);
```

and added the right tasks in the watch config and now it works!

Answer (score 2):

you can rename the original "watch" task of the plugin to an own for example "watchfiles". The following should be working:

```
    watchfiles: {
        coffee: {
            files: ['coffee/*.coffee'],
            tasks: ['coffeelint:server', 'coffee:server']
        },
        compass: {
            files: ['sass/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
            tasks: ['compass:server']
        }
```

...

```
grunt.renameTask('watch',
    'watchfiles');

grunt.registerTask('watch', [
    'clean:server',
    'coffeelint:server',
    'coffee:server',
    'compass:server',
    'watchfiles'
]);
```